# How can I calculate this space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening, I'm trying to calculate this quotient vector space $C^1[-1, 1]/D$ Where $D$ is the following subspace of $C^1[-1, 1]$. $D=\{f \in C^1[-1, 1]:f(x) - xf'(x) = 0\}$.

My work:

I want to find the equivalence class of a function $g(x)\in C^1[-1, 1]$. For this, I also consider the function $h(x)\in C^1[-1, 1]$. Then we will say that $hRg$ iff $(h-g)(x)\in D$, but $(h-g)(x)\in D$ iff $(h-g)(x)-x(h-g)'(x)=0$.

And from there I wonder what is the next step? In other words, what does this vector space represent?

From here I'm stuck, how to find the equivalence class of $g(x)$?, how do I construct in quotient? Any help is welcome. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if $f \in C^1[-1, 1]$ and $f(x) - xf'(x) = 0$, then there is $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=cx$. If we put $f_0(x):=x$ , then

$$ D=\{cf_0: c \in \mathbb R \}.$$

The equivalence relation   $"\sim"$  on  $C^1[-1, 1]$ is defined by

$f \sim g$  iff $f-g \in D$. Therefore the equivalence class of $g$ is given by

$$\{g+cf_0: c \in \mathbb R\}.$$

Comment: If we call the set $W=\{g+cf_0: c \in \mathbb R\}.$ So the last thing you describe in your answer is the set $f+W$ or $g+W$? And really thank you very much for your valuable contribution!

Comment: By the way, you know that I am doing an exercise similar to the first, but I also have the same doubts as to what class of equivalence defines the set and how to raise quotient space, I do not know if you can help me with it, $C^1[-1, 1]/S$ when $S=\{f \in C^1[-1, 1]:f(-1) =f(1)\}$?. Thank you so much!!!